# Sharepoint WS - change root folder for all sub-items in the same library

Tags: web-services, sharepoint-2013

Using Sharepoint 2013 **web services** I'm trying to "rename" root folder in the library (root folder by my definition is the first folder in library).

If new name (target) does not exist already, renaming is easy, I just change the BaseName:

```
var batch2 = new XmlDocument().CreateElement("Batch");
batch2.SetAttribute("OnError", "Continue");
batch2.InnerXml = "<Method ID=\"1\" Cmd=\"Update\"><Field Name=\"ID\">"+oldId+"</Field><Field Name=\"BaseName\">"+newName+"</Field></Method>";
client.UpdateListItems("MY LIBRARY", batch2);
```

But if folder already exists - nothing, obviously, happens.

My libraries file structure is this:

```
MY LIB
-AAA
    --aaa
        aaa.jpg
        aaa1.jpg
    --aaa1
        aaa11.jpg
-BBB
    --bbb
        bbb.jpg
        bbb1.jpg
    --bbb1
        bbb11.jpg
```

So, how can I change aaa, aaa1 items so that folder BBB becomes their root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Moving" subfolders to other folders is done by changing BaseName field. Nowhere in documentation this is said.

So to move `aaa` subfolder to `BBB` folder all you need is this query:
`<Method ID=\"1\" Cmd=\"Update\"><Field Name=\"ID\">[ID of aaa folder]</Field><Field Name=\"BaseName\">BBB/aaa</Field></Method>`

All files are "moved" accordingly

God I hate Sharepoint.